# Kali Linux: Texts are squeezed

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, kali-linux

I am using Kali Linux and I installed `gnome-tweak-tool` for applying `lid-close-action` but after installing that, all the menu texts are squeezed now and also scrollbar in terminal is not there anymore. I have then uninstalled that but my problem was not resolved.

I have reinstalled `gnome-tweak-tool` if that fix my problem but still my problem persists. Restarting my system didn't work. One more thing to note, I am on my real system, not on any virtual machine. Below is my screenshot of that squeezed text

[image: Squeezed Text Screenshot]

Comment: Your GTK theme or gnome shell theme are acting up. Please make sure they are the correct skins, (e.g. kali). *this is under tweak tool*. If the problem persists you can try getting a new gnome theme.

Comment: I was already using `Kali` theme but the problem was not with that. I finally able to resolve my problem. Posting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was occurring due to some disturbance with `gnome`
So, I update my system with the following and problem got resolved.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```